# Is there a way to save Firebase real-time database data when an Internet connection is not available?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an attendance Android app in Kotlin. In this app, a students list is available offline with an SQLite database.

For attendance saving, I am using Firebase Realtime Database.

But, I want to make app which can work in offline mode also. And upload attendance when an Internet connection is available, even after restarting the application.

Comment: You're already using sqlite db when internet is off for students, why don't do the same for attendances?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I cannot see any benefit of implementing this mechanism since the Realtime Database has its own offline persistence mechanism. According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities):

> Firebase apps automatically handle temporary network interruptions. Cached data is available while offline and Firebase resends any writes when network connectivity is restored.

> When you enable disk persistence, your app writes the data locally to the device so your app can maintain its state while offline, even if the user or operating system restarts the app.

So while offline, you can continue using the app. In Android, this can be simply done using:

```
Firebase.database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

To enable offline persistence in Firebase Realtime Database, you can use the following code:

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`

This line of code should be placed before any other Firebase Realtime Database operations in your app, preferably in the onCreate() method of your MainActivity or in your Application class.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies here since your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: This is not AI generated information.

Comment: Good to hear - Thanks for the reply!